# I am not getting all info from my contact form.From: no email & body-no email and telephone,but i can get message

Tags: php, forms

Here is my contact form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <label><span class="text-form">Full Name:</span>
                  <input type="text" name="cf_name">
                </label>
                <label><span class="text-form">E-mail:</span>
                  <input type="text" name="cf_email">
                </label>
                <label><span class="text-form">Telephone:</span>
                  <input type="text" name="cf_phone">
                </label>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="text-form">Message:</div>
                  <div class="extra-wrap">
                    <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                <div class="buttons"><a class="button-2" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').reset()">Clear</a>
<a class="button-2" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()">Send</a></div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
```

I have changed several items in the code at first i was getting no emails then i was getting email with no content and now it missing the From: email address and in the body of email no email address and no phone number but i do get the message.Im stumped

And here is my contact.php

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_phone'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = '2waylogistics@gmail.com';
$subject = '2waylogistics contact form '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
window.location = 'thank_you.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@2waylogistics.com');
        window.location = 'contacts.html';
</script>   
<?
php
}
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the PHP in `contact.php`

Comment: give me a chance, thanks any thoughts?

Comment: I checked your edit and it contains the same information twice, as previously stated. We need to see stuff like `<?php $cf_name=$_POST['cf_name'];` etc. `mail($to....` etc. etc.

Comment: im trying but it wont let me post the code for some reason??

Comment: I noticed your previous edit, and you had forgotten to make a carriage return after your `And here is my contact.php` --- just put it in there, and I'll have a look at it after. And make sure it's PHP and not a copy of your HTML form.

Comment: Ok, for one thing, you have a missing dot in `$body_message = 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";` change it to `$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";` which is most likely the cause. Change it and try it again.

Comment: I see it already?? man u guys are tuff

Comment: okay i tried it with the dot to and same thing??

Comment: One of the problems is this: `<?
php
}
?>` you seperated the `<?` from `php`

Comment: aha that why im getting phone in email spot

Comment: it did that when i pasted it thats the way i have itbut let me change the phone and email part...one sec

Comment: that did it thanks one more thing can you add two more fields for me i have been looking at this stuff for two days..i need (Load info) under the load info (ex:p/u, drop/off, lb, h x w x L & Locations)

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that both `j08691` and I have already done enough to fix the initial problem. It's up to you to do that, unless `j08691` wants to have a go at it; I have other work to do. Plus the question needs to be closed properly.

Comment: okay im doing it now if i have any more issues ill come back, thanks you all!!

Comment: @user3163660 This question needs to be closed. **Click on the White checkmark [in my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20958802/1415724), till it turns Green.**

Comment: okay got that closed sorry!!

Comment: i noticed an issue if i hit the send button it sends the email any way.Its not supposed to do that it should have required fields and not send if the form is not completely filled out.what is wrong? How can i add capatcha??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 issues with your code.

1) A missing dot in

```
$body_message = 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
             ^
```

2) Seperating `<?` from `php` (which would have thrown a parse error)

```
<?
php
}
?>
```

3) And what `j08691` posted in [**an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958683/1415724).

Now try:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = '2waylogistics@gmail.com';
$subject = '2waylogistics contact form '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
window.location = 'thank_you.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@2waylogistics.com');
        window.location = 'contacts.html';
</script>   
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You re-used the same variable for phone and email:

```
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_phone'];
```

Try:

```
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
```